# What's the best way to make server calls in ejs templates in sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js, ejs

I have a ejs template that renders a view. User interacts on this page. I am capturing user interaction in ejs template itself.

Now, I would like to make a server-side call to the endpoint '/validate' from within this ejs template.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is probably to use `<ajax-form>`, a new component available in Sails.js v1.  For example, assuming you're using Cloud SDK and your action is named `validate`:

```
<ajax-form action="validate">
</ajax-form>
```

For more related examples, check out the [Ration example and/or Platzi course](https://ration.io/).